# calculating multiple variable in column based on comparing dates in rows as well as header of columns

Tags: r

i am unable to think of an easy method to do this.

Sample data is :

```
set.seed(101)
b=sample(seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2010/1/10"), "days"), 3)
f1=data.frame(a=1:length(b), b=b)
col_names=paste(c('x', 'y'), sort(rep(seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2010/1/10"), "days"), 2)), sep = '')
set.seed((102))
f2 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5,30, replace = T), ncol = length(col_names), nrow = nrow(f1)))
names(f2)=col_names
f3=data.frame(f1, f2)
```

or

```
dput(f3)
structure(list(a = 1:3, b = structure(c(14613, 14610, 14615), class = "Date"), 
    x2010.01.01 = c(3L, 2L, 4L), y2010.01.01 = c(3L, 0L, 2L), 
    x2010.01.02 = c(5L, 1L, 5L), y2010.01.02 = c(2L, 5L, 4L), 
    x2010.01.03 = c(4L, 2L, 3L), y2010.01.03 = c(5L, 4L, 2L), 
    x2010.01.04 = c(5L, 5L, 5L), y2010.01.04 = c(3L, 3L, 3L), 
    x2010.01.05 = c(1L, 2L, 0L), y2010.01.05 = c(2L, 2L, 2L), 
    x2010.01.06 = c(3L, 2L, 4L), y2010.01.06 = c(3L, 0L, 2L), 
    x2010.01.07 = c(5L, 1L, 5L), y2010.01.07 = c(2L, 5L, 4L), 
    x2010.01.08 = c(4L, 2L, 3L), y2010.01.08 = c(5L, 4L, 2L), 
    x2010.01.09 = c(5L, 5L, 5L), y2010.01.09 = c(3L, 3L, 3L), 
    x2010.01.10 = c(1L, 2L, 0L), y2010.01.10 = c(2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Im trying to create new columns based on comparing b date to column header. im calculating 1 day avg, 3 day avg and so on.

In 1st case the date is 4th jan which imply that 1 day col would be x2010.01.04, 3 day avg would include (x2010.01.04,x2010.01.03,x2010.01.02) and so on. This need to be done for x and y variable both.

Finally op should look like

```
a          b      oneday_avg_x oneday_avg_y threeday_avg_x threeday_avg_y
1 1 2010-01-04          5           3   (5+4+5)/3=4.6            3.3
2 2 2010-01-01          2           0              2              0
3 3 2010-01-06          4           2              3             2.3
```

Let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right seed? I am getting some different dates for the same seed.

Comment: For me `f3$b` returns `[1] "2010-01-09" "2010-01-10" "2010-01-06"`. Is it supposed to be that?

Comment: What R version you are using? Mine is `3.6.1`  there were some changes in `seed` recently I guess. Can you share data using `dput`.

Comment: will share in a while

Comment: 3.5.3 works fine. I added dput output to the question

Comment: Thanks Jimbou! My R version is R version 3.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` for `"x"` and `"y"` values. We remove first leading `"x"` and `"y"` from column names, convert it to Date and `match` it with `b` value. Return that index along with `mean` of previous 3 index from the `apply` call. As `apply` converts everything to characters, we use `type.convert` to convert columns to appropriate classes.

```
x_cols <- grep("^x", names(f3))
y_cols <- grep("^y", names(f3))

out <- f3[1:2]
out[c("oneday_avg_x", "threeday_avg_x")] <- t(apply(f3[c(2, x_cols)], 1, function(x) {
  inds <- match(as.Date(x[[1]]), as.Date(sub("^x", "", names(x)), "%Y.%m.%d"))
  c(x[inds], mean(as.numeric(x[(inds - 2) : inds]), na.rm = TRUE))
}))

out[c("oneday_avg_y", "threeday_avg_y")] <- t(apply(f3[c(2, y_cols)], 1, function(x) {
   inds <- match(as.Date(x[[1]]), as.Date(sub("^y", "", names(x)), "%Y.%m.%d"))
   c(x[inds], mean(as.numeric(x[(inds - 2) : inds]), na.rm = TRUE))
}))

out <- type.convert(out)

out
#  a          b oneday_avg_x threeday_avg_x oneday_avg_y threeday_avg_y
#1 1 2010-01-04            5         4.6667            3         3.3333
#2 2 2010-01-01            2         2.0000            0         0.0000
#3 3 2010-01-06            4         3.0000            2         2.3333
```

---

**EDIT**

A more scalable solution which can handle multiple day averages by using single `apply`

```
x_cols <- grep("^x", names(f3))
y_cols <- grep("^y", names(f3))
names(f3)[-(1:2)] <- gsub("\\.", "-", sub(".{1}", "", names(f3)[-(1:2)]))
out <- f3[1:2]
num <- c(1, 3)
new_cols  <- c(outer(num, c("x", "y"), function(x, y) paste0(x, "_day_avg_", y)))

out[new_cols] <- t(apply(f3, 1, function(x) {
     x_ind <- match(x[[2]], names(x)[x_cols])
     x_vals <- sapply(num, function(y) 
       mean(as.numeric(x[x_cols][max((x_ind - y + 1), 1):x_ind])))
     y_ind <- match(x[[2]], names(x)[y_cols])
     y_vals <- sapply(num, function(y) 
       mean(as.numeric(x[y_cols][max((y_ind - y + 1), 1):y_ind])))
     c(x_vals, y_vals)
}))


out
#  a          b 1_day_avg_x 3_day_avg_x 1_day_avg_y 3_day_avg_y
#1 1 2010-01-04           5    4.666667           3    3.333333
#2 2 2010-01-01           2    2.000000           0    0.000000
#3 3 2010-01-06           4    3.000000           2    2.333333
```

Comment: i get a warning but works fine. also what if this is not limited to x and y, like i have few variable x1,x2,x3 and i want to find oit 1day avg, 3 day avg, 7 day avg so on.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli warning is because for example for row 2, we are trying to find mean of previous 3 entries which is not present. If you don't have `x` and `y` in columns how do you differentiate between which variables should come under `oneday_avg_x` and which ones under `oneday_avg_y` ?

Comment: Yeah i get that. thanks for your help. I wanted the solution be more general. Like we can have x,y,z,etc columns. This works out too. thanks again.

Comment: 1 more issue with the solution would be if b falls outside range(1:10) jan lets say 11 jan than NA would be returned.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli I have tried to make the solution better and more scalable to include more number of days.